# opencart download from new server

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

Actually i want to change `opencart` download routh to new website, already download folder is:

> /system/download

**config.php**

```
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/system/download/');
```

and here is code from `controller/account/download.php`

```
if ($download_info) {
    $file = DIR_DOWNLOAD . $download_info['filename'];
    $mask = basename($download_info['mask']);

    if (!headers_sent()) {
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . ($mask ? $mask : basename($file)) . '"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

            if (ob_get_level()) {
                ob_end_clean();
            }

            readfile($file, 'rb');

            exit();
        } else {
            exit('Error: Could not find file ' . $file . '!');
        }
    } else {
        exit('Error: Headers already sent out!');
    }
} else {
    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/download', '', 'SSL'));
}
```

i want to buy a new server just for downloading, and now i want change opencart download route to new server. how can i do this?

Already download system is like this:

> https://example.com/index.php?route=account/download/download&download_id=16

and it will get file from this directory:

> /system/download/example.zip

but i want to get file from new server:

> https://newserver.com/download/example.zip

Is it possible? I changed `DIR_DOWNLOAD` but no success. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, go with this easily:

```
$newserv = "http://newserver.com/";
$file = $newserv . $download_info['filename'];
$mask = basename($download_info['mask']);
```